# how to grab values from jQuery .html function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

how can I grab values from jQuery .html() function for the following piece of code?

```
$('#div_id').html('<input name="textbox1" id="txt1" type="text" size="40" maxlength="350">');
```

The code works like this, on clicking a button a text box is generated. 
I have another button(with id="btn2"), clicking on this button I want to grab the values from this textbox(with the id="txt1") and to assign it into a variable.

The action code for the btn2 which I have made:

```
$('#btn2').bind("click", function(){
       variable = $('#txt1').val();
       alert(variable);
});
```

I am not able to retrieve the value of the textbox since it is generated using .html()
Kindly help me to solve this problem!

Thanks,
~Ganesh

Comment: i am not able to retrieve the value of the textbox since it is generated using .html() in jQuery.

Comment: Once it's generated, that should not be a problem.  The "HTML" is in the document.  JavaScript should be able to see it.

Comment: To me it seems like your code should work. Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y46Pg/

Comment: Once the HTML is parsed into DOM elements and appended to document which is what `.html()` does, it is no different from other elements. Ensure that you don't have duplicated IDs.

Comment: When are you adding the second button and the click binding to that button?  It might be an issue of the JavaScript trigger not having been attached to the button before it was created.

Comment: Here's a Fiddle proof-of-concept based on your idea. http://jsfiddle.net/f5fVQ/1/  It should work fine.  Perhaps if you give additional information regarding the second button?  The bug might be in there.  *oops* missed Yoggi's fiddle.

Comment: As @Yoggi stated this code should work fine as is assuming that you're not invoking the `bind` method prior to invoking the `html` method. You may want to consider the `live` jQuery method...

Comment: Sorry... meant `on`... get my versions of jQuery mixed up. :-)

Comment: Wait... never mind... that might not help you at all since it's not that the BUTTON element doesn't yet exist but that the TEXTAREA may not yet have been created... sorry for the mix-up...

Comment: It's probably because he's not waiting for the document to load and so the bind is not working, therefore it is not calling the callback.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your initial text box generation code is missing the `value` attribute.

It works for me if I use something like:

```
$('#div_id').html('<input name="textbox1" id="txt1" type="text" size="40" maxlength="350" value="test">');
```

Comment: what!?!?  You don't need the `value` attribute when creating an input type=textbox because the value will always be what's entered inside the textbox

Comment: Agree with @wirey, in this example http://jsfiddle.net/Y46Pg/ there is no need for value.

Comment: @Yoggi @wirey From reading the question, I believed that OP expected a value to be available immediately after using `html`. Considering his/her code is not incorrect, I reasoned that OP might not be aware that a default value was not set.

Comment: Creating a default should not have solved his problem. It should have just alerted null (or similar) without it until text was entered.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be working because you are not waiting for the document to load. That would explain why all the fiddles being posted work and your code does not. I'm fairly certain JS fiddle will wait before running the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div_id').html('<input name="textbox1" id="txt1" type="text" size="40" maxlength="350">');
    $('#btn2').bind("click", function () {
        var variable = $('#txt1').val();
        alert(variable);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

$(function () {
            $('#div_id').html($(''));
        });
        $('#btn2').live("click", function () {
            var variable = $('#txt1').val();
            alert(variable);
        });